# Best way for Unique Random String for MySQL Long table

Tags: mysql, database, random, relational-database

I know how to create random chars both at PHP and MySQL but the question is that I have to create a 4 char random string for a table of 10 thousand or so rows. What way is the best to make sure it will remain unique?

I can use a longer string if I need to but not longer then 12.

Just to make it simple, table exists I need to add an extra column and fill it with a 4 char random string and keys must remain unique.

Comment: The requirement isn't clear - are you trying to update the table with this new random-length-random-value string, and ensure it's unique for each row? It sounds like then each new row would have to get a new random-length-random-value string?

Comment: Did I misinterpret your question with my answer below? Do you want each entire string to be unique or each one of the 4+ chars that are in your string to be unique?.

Comment: I've read the question 4 times now, and it's not explicitly stated. It's a collection of fragment statements in the question and comments that aren't cohesively put together to plainly lay out what's needed. **Careful not to talk down to people who're willing to help**, lest your questions go unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option:

Put all you possible characters in a table with only one column.

```
val
------
0
1
...
9
a
b
...
z
```

Use this query

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.val,b.val,c.val,d.val)
FROM chars AS a
JOIN chars AS b
JOIN chars AS c
JOIN chars AS d
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10000
```

---

On the other hand if you need to get one ID at a time I see two approaches.

#### A. If you have a lot of unassigned IDs available.

In this case you just generate an ID and see if it's free. If not try another one.

#### B. If you want to keep you assigned IDs and the available IDs in the same magnitude level.

In this case it would be best to pre-generate all your IDs, shuffle them, and when you need one just pick the next available one. Say put them all in a table, and when you assign one from that table, you remove it so it can't be picked again.

If your allowed characters are `0-9a-z` this means the table will occupy 36<sup>4</sup>. That's just a couple of MB.

Comment: @Alin: thanks for your answer but the issue is that the table is not stopping there like i have to insert data everyday.

Comment: The answer depends on how many possible IDs there are and/or how many you need to retrieve at a time.

Comment: its around 10,000 now and grows like 20-50 per day.

Comment: @Omeid Herat No, I mean how may can you generate with those 4 chars? What are the allowed chars?

Comment: You have all the info you need to make a decision in the answer. I'll give you a personal preference based on what I understood about your scenario: Make the ID 6 chars long and when you add something generate IDs until you find a free one. You can keep a list of pre-generated free IDs if you want to make sure you only do one try when adding. And have a cron or something that keeps adding to that list once in a while.

Comment: @Alen Thanks for your answer I like the Second way.

Answer (score 2):

As those strings need to be unique, why not use a numeric auto-increment value and then convert that to a character based value similar to the conversion of decimal to hex.

If you choose the e.g. all characters and digits you simply need to create a routine that will convert an integer to a "base 62" number.

Comment: A good idea. The only problem would be that the resulting strings will not be random.

Comment: and when I need to retrieve the row based on that information I will have to decode it right ?

Comment: @Alin: yes, but "random" and "unique" contradict themselves to a certain extent. @Omeid: not necessarily as you can use the "generated" value just as well to retrieve the data.

Comment: Doing both random **and** unique seemed to me to be the real problem to solve. And it is possible to do both, but not straight-forward. See my answer for to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `DISTINCT` keyword.

For example, the following query will only return unique rows by which you can validate that your 4 char random string remains unique:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT random_strings FROM chars;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but wish I had the values there, i wan't to create random char's with length of four for each row.

Answer (score 0):

This may be lengthy, but would allow you to create what you need:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION gen_alphanum () RETURNS CHAR(4)
    RETURN 
    ELT(FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * (50-1))), 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m  ','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y', 'z',
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y', 'Z',);
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got the code in MySQL for creating these random valued strings.

Consider this option:

- create a [User Defined Function in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html). Have this function run the SQL statements to generate and return this new random string. Ensure that you use `NOT EXISTS(SELECT MyRandomString FROM MyTable)` within that creation statement to check that the random string doesn't already exist in the table.
- When inserting new rows, use this function's return value to assign to the `MyRandomString` column.
- to update the data existing, simply:

```
 UPDATE MyTable
 SET    MyRandomString = fn_CreateSomeRandomString()
```

- when inserting:

```
 INSERT INTO MyTable (foo, bar, MyRandomString) 
 VALUES ('','', fn_CreateSomeRandomString());
```

Here's a [sample of that UDF on PasteBin](http://pastebin.ca/2016531).

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL 5.6, you can use TO_BASE64 as follows:

```
select LEFT( TO_BASE64( SHA(rand()) ), 6 ) ;
```

Alternatively if you don't have 5.6,

```
DELIMITER //

drop function if exists randChr //
create function randChr()
returns char
BEGIN
  IF RAND() <= 0.5 THEN -- Lowercase
    return CHAR( 97 + 25*rand() ) ;
  ELSE -- uc
    return CHAR( 65 + 25*rand() ) ;
  END IF;
END //

drop function if exists randString //
create function randString( len int )
returns varchar(255)
BEGIN
  SET @n = 0;
  SET @res = '' ;
  REPEAT
    SET @res = concat( @res, randChr() ) ;
    set @n = @n + 1 ;
  UNTIL @n >= len END REPEAT;
  return @res ;
END //

DELIMITER ;

-- USE:
select randString( 5 );
select randString( 60 );
```